# Por que métodos nativos como navigator.onLine de verificação de rede não funcionam corretamente?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, pwa

Estou criando uma aplicação PWA e o primeiro passo, obviamente será verificar a rede. Existem três métodos conhecidos:

- usar a variável global 'navigator.onLine'
- usar os eventos 'ononline' e 'onoffline' na tag 'body'
- realizar um 'xmlhttprequest' como função alternativa às duas primeiras que são nativas

Meu código de teste está assim:

```
function navon(){
  alert("Estou online? " + navigator.onLine);
}
```

na tag 'body':

```
<body ononline="alert('ON#')" onoffline="alert('OFF#')">
```

e a função alternativa:

```
var rede = function (){
  var request = new window.XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
  // request.open('HEAD', 'http://www.teste02.dev/robots.txt', true);
  request.open('HEAD', 'http://localhost/sandbox/teste02.dev/public/robots.txt', true);
  request.timeout = 5750;
  request.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    console.log('We seem to be online!', event);
    online = true;
  });
  var offlineAlert = function(event) {
    console.log('We are likely offline:', event);
  }
  request.addEventListener('error', offlineAlert);
  request.addEventListener('timeout', offlineAlert);
  request.send(null);
}
```

A página de teste:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<body ononline="alert('ON#')" onoffline="alert('OFF#')">
  <div id="">
    <button type="button" id="button" onclick="rede()">REQUEST</button>
  </div>
  <div id="">
    <button type="button" id="button" onclick="navon()">NAVIGATOR.onLine</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Realizei testes em plataformas Windows, Linux e Android, em localhost e em dominio online. A tabela a seguir explica minha conclusão de que somente a função alternativa funciona corretamente em ambiente de produção, ou seja melhor que as funções nativas feitas para isso.
[image: Tabela de comparação de testes. Servidor=dominio online]

Eis a dúvida, é normal a função nativa não funcionar bem em todos os navegadores e plataformas ou eu que estou errando? Eu gostaria de  simplesmente usar o navigator.onLine sem erro.

Comment: Não sei se tu chegaste a ver [isto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine#Browser_compatibility) mas tem alguma informação lá que talvez ajude.

Comment: Já havia visto, mas as versões que testei são mais atuais. O que pude perceber é que depende do S.O., pois Edge funciona perfeitamente no Windows pois é nativo, e Firefox funciona perfeitamente no Linux que no meu caso é nativo, mas quando uso um browser não nativo no windows, como Firefox e Chrome as funções ditas nativas só funcionam com a ferramenta "work-offline", o que indica que realmente há suporte pelos navegadores. O que vejo é que a informação de que o computador está offline não é repassada aos  browsers pelo Windows.

Comment: Se queres que funcione em todos os casos é melhor usares o `XMLHttpRequest`. Há informação em inglês nestas perguntas: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189430); [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3181080); [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14283124).